# I am getting a Parsing Error: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";" in React

Tags: reactjs

While trying to bring back components to app.js and running the react code by npm start, I am getting a parsing error which is:

```
    ./src/App.js
      Line 5:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

      3 | import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
      4 |
    > 5 | import "CreateTodo" from "./components/create-todo.component";
        |                     ^
      6 | import "EditTodo" from "./components/edit-todo.component";
      7 | import "TodoList" from "./components/todo-list.component";
```

My Codes in App.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Rout, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import "CreateTodo" from "./components/create-todo.component";
import "EditTodo" from "./components/edit-todo.component";
import "TodoList" from "./components/todo-list.component";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
        <div className="container">
            <h2>MERN Stack To Do App</h2>
            <Route path="/" exact component = {TodoList} /> 
            <Route path="/edit/:id" component = {EditTodo} />
            <Route path= "/create" component ={CreateTodo} />
       </div>
    <Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What's the error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove the `""` from `CreateTodo`, like so: `import CreateTodo from "./components/create-todo.component"`; and from the other imports too. It should not be a `string`, but an `object` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have wrong imports,

```
import "CreateTodo" from "./components/create-todo.component";
import "EditTodo" from "./components/edit-todo.component";
import "TodoList" from "./components/todo-list.component";
```

import name should not be string,

```
import CreateTodo from "./components/create-todo.component";
import EditTodo from "./components/edit-todo.component";
import TodoList from "./components/todo-list.component";
```

Comment: below page will help your understanding
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am not getting this error anymore. But I am getting a new error which is:  Line 14:  'Route' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

Comment: Because you have wrong import here also `import {BrowserRouter as Router, Rout, Link} from "react-router-dom";` Here `Route` is written as `Rout`.

Comment: Thanks, It was a spelling mistake. haha

Answer (score 1):

```
import CreateTodo from "./components/create-todo.component";
import EditTodo from "./components/edit-todo.component";
import TodoList from "./components/todo-list.component";
```

These statements allow you to import CreateTodo from the component mentioned. Instead of importing "CreateTodo" as string import them as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Import can not be a string. so import like this

```
import CreateTodo from "./components/create-todo.component";
```

And in below-mentioned line Rout should be Route

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Rout, Link} from "react-router-dom";
```